# Angularjs - auto submit the first item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to select the first item in my ng-repeat as soon the list is loaded to the user, is there an easy way to do that?

Right now im using the ng-click, but i dont know how to automatic click that first item.

This is my ng-repeat

```
<div ng-hide="hideMembershipSection" ng-repeat="membership in memberships" class="row">
<div class="membership-box col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-8">
    <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="/images/onlinesalg_ny/{{ membership.image }}">

    <h1 class="text-uppercase">{{ membership.titel_onlinesalg }}</h1>
    <p>{{ membership.onlinesalg_produktbeskrivelse }}</p>

</div><!-- col-lg-9 -->

<div class="membership-box__price col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 text-center">
    <h1>
        <small>Kr.</small>
        {{ membership.pris }},-
    </h1>
    <button ng-click="selectMembership(membership)" type="button" ng-class='{"btn-success": membership.pid == success}' class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="membership.pid == success">{{ membership.pid === success ? "valgt" : "vælg"}}</button>

</div><!-- col-lg-9 -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller, after the code where you load the list into `$scope.memberships`, what about using the line:

```
selectMembership($scope.memberships[0]);
```

This is essentially doing what ng-click is doing, but after the list is loaded. It depends on what your selectMembership function does though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-init` to select first element by default as in `ng-init="ngModelFieldName=memberships[0]`

i dont know the name of the ng-model hence gave the name `ngModelFieldName`

```
 <div ng-hide="hideMembershipSection" ng-repeat="membership in memberships" ng-init="ngModelFieldName=memberships[0]" class="row">
```